# preg_replace() with variable in replacement string eats up first character

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace a version string but it always eats up my fists letter of the version string until I put a space in between: `Version:$1 $new_version`

But I do not want to do that and would like to understand what happens here.

File contents:

```
Version:    4.4.4
```

Relevant part of my code:

```
$new_version = 6.6.6
$new_main_file_content = preg_replace(
    '/Version:([ ]*)[0-9\.]+/', 
    "Version:$1$new_version", 
    file_get_contents($main_file) 
);
```

Without the space the output is `Version:.6.6` and with it, the output is right but just one space too much. I have tried using the curly brackets as well, but... no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a replacement gotcha. From the [PHP manual documentation on `preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace):

> When working with a replacement pattern where a backreference is immediately followed by another number (i.e.: placing a literal number immediately after a matched pattern), you cannot use the familiar `\\1` notation for your backreference. `\\11`, for example, would confuse `preg_replace()` since it does not know whether you want the `\\1` backreference followed by a literal `1`, or the `\\11` backreference followed by nothing. In this case the solution is to use `\${1}1`. This creates an isolated `$1` backreference, leaving the `1` as a literal.

This should do what you want:

```
preg_replace( '/Version:([ ]*)[0-9\.]+/', 'Version:${1}'.$new_version, ...);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/142516)

Comment: Don't mind previous comment. I just and the wrong replacemetn already written into the file. This was exactly it.