# appending to each regex result

Tags: php, regex

So let's say we have a text like "CS x1CD x2CE x3"

What I want to do is replace each x1 with x1\n, x2 with x2\n, x3 with x3\n, etc.  During runtime it is not known before hand what those values will be, but basically after each x[0-9]+ we want to append a newline.

How would I do this?  I tried using regex such as

```
preg_replace("/x[0-9]+/", "${1}\n", $request['item_name']);
```

But that doesn't work as it just uses the first result.

Comment: Use `0` instead of `1` : `'${0}' . "\n"` :P

Comment: The curly brace regex syntax would only work inside single-quotes. And if you use single-quotes, `\n` will be interpreted as literal `\n` (and not as a newline character). The solution is to use what @HamZa said. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH6rN5).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid to refer to a capturing group with `\K`:

```
$result = preg_replace("/x[0-9]+\K/", "\n", $request['item_name']);
```

`\K` removes all on the left from match result.

If your server is running on a linux/unix system, you can skip a good part of the curly/double/single quotes/newline problem using PHP_EOL:

```
$result = preg_replace("/x[0-9]+/", '$0' . PHP_EOL, $request['item_name']);
```

Comment: Man, that's Klever! +1

Comment: You beat me to that one =)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the following instead.

```
preg_replace('/x[0-9]+/', '${0}' . "\n", $request['item_name']);
```

See [live demo](https://eval.in/146358).

Comment: It's better to use `${1}` instead, because of a ["replacement gotcha"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23314432/1438393) that `preg_replace()` has.

Comment: @AmalMurali: There is no ambiguity here.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Not currently, no. But there's a possibility. Better safe than sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Live Demo**](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/56b)

Try this:

```
 preg_replace("/(x[0-9]+)/","${0}\n",$request['item_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$string  = $request['item_name'];
$string  = preg_replace('/(x\d+)/', '$1\n', $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

***DEMO***

http://ideone.com/quh4M1